# CSS3 button with animation issue on iPad

Tags: html, css, animation

I've a burger icon, like this - when clicked it becomes a "X" using only CSS3 ([website link here](http://188.166.163.149/de/))

[image]

But my client are seeing something like this (only on iPad):

[image]

My question is:

1) What can be causing this?

2) How can I reproduce errors like this as I don't have an iPad and resizing the browser (developer tools) doesn't reproduce the error?

```css
.mobile-nav {
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 10103;
      bottom: 40%;
      left: 45%;
      margin-top: -230px;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    .mobile-nav .mobile-nav-bg {
      /* this is the stretching navigation background */
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 10102;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      border-radius: 30px !important;
      background: #fff;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      webkit-transition: height .2s, box-shadow .2s;
      -webkit-transition: height .2s, box-shadow .2s;
      transition: height .2s, box-shadow .2s;
    }
    .mobile-nav-trigger {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 10103;
      top: 2px;
      right: 0;
      height: 60px;
      width: 60px;
      border-radius: 50% !important;
      overflow: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      color: transparent;
      pointer-events: auto;
    }
    .mobile-nav-trigger span,
    .mobile-nav-trigger span::after,
    .mobile-nav-trigger span::before {
      /* this is the hamburger icon */
      position: absolute;
      width: 16px;
      height: 2px;
      background-color: #000;
    }
    .mobile-nav-trigger span {
      /* middle line of the hamburger icon */
      webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
      -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
      transition: background-color 0.2s;
      left: 50%;
      top: auto;
      bottom: 50%;
      right: auto;
      webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
              transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    }
    .mobile-nav-trigger span::after,
    .mobile-nav-trigger span::before {
      /* top and bottom lines of the hamburger icon */
      content: '';
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      webkit-transition: transform 0.2s;
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s;
      transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s;
      transition: transform 0.2s;
      transition: transform 0.2s, -webkit-transform 0.2s;
    }
    .mobile-nav-trigger span::before {
      webkit-transform: translateY(-6px);
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-6px);
              transform: translateY(-6px);
    }
    .mobile-nav-trigger span::after {
      webkit-transform: translateY(6px);
      -webkit-transform: translateY(6px);
              transform: translateY(6px);
    }
    
    .nav-is-visible .mobile-nav-trigger span {
  background-color: transparent; }

.nav-is-visible .mobile-nav-trigger span::before {
  webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg); }

.nav-is-visible .mobile-nav-trigger span::after {
  webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://188.166.163.149/static/theme/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('nav').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('nav-is-visible');
    });
  });
</script>


<div class="box">
<nav class="mobile-nav visible-xs visible-sm nav-is-visible"><a class="mobile-nav-trigger menu-trigger" href="#0"><span aria-hidden="true"></span></a><ul><li></li></ul><span aria-hidden="true" class="mobile-nav-bg"></span></nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using a Mac, or have access to one?

Comment: No, I'm using windows, but maybe I can get a mac for this time. there's the only way?

Comment: You can view it on chrome dev tools itself using device toolbar in inspect toolbar

Comment: I was able to find the icon coming up on the ipad mode

Comment: FYI: The icon looks ok on my ipad mini 2.  But it is invisible as you describe on my ipod.  Unfortunately, the only way I've found to get past this is to test your application on as wide an array of real-world devices, and to be familiar with the various quirks that popular OSs / devices / browsers throw up.

Comment: too bad because I don't have an iPad to test it :( maybe I'll have to find another way to show this button, a more "crossdevice" way than just CSS3 animation.

Comment: I dont think what you're doing is wrong - CSS3 should be handled easily across the vast majority of public users...  I've just noticed something odd about your vendor-prefixes that may be causing it!...

Answer (score 0):

In many cases your vendor prefixes are not correct. For example:

```
.mobile-nav-trigger span {
  ...
  webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
  ...
}
```

The first statement of these 3 is not legal in any browser I know of.  The first line (no dash before "webkit") needs to be removed in all cases.  The other two lines are valid; and should be present in all cases.

Although I haven't tested this definitively, it certain could be causing the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: @MaxFerreira I found another example online, with no broken vendor prefixes, and this works fine on all my devices: http://joren.co/sass-burger/

Comment: I've used the https://autoprefixer.github.io/ to clean this cases, but I was not able to test as I don't have in iPad :( any suggestions about that?

Answer (score 0):

Sign up for a free Apple Developer account, Download [XCode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) and you can run the iOS device emulator as an iPad. That will allow you to test your potential fixes. You do need a Mac, however. But, that's the only way I know how you could do it other than buying or borrowing an iPad.